# How to reduce the insulating effect of new socks by "breaking them in" more quickly?

Tags: clothing

I have to walk a lot of miles each day when its extremely hot. The socks make a huge difference regarding how hot I get. I like socks (always ankle high of course) that are *very* stretched-out, thus making the cotton very thin. This allows my feet to breath because I always walk in old running shoes.

New socks are just horrible!!! Trust me, you do not want to do a 8-km walk in 85" heat in new socks. Running in new socks for a few weeks before walking in them does not really help stretch them out. I'm not sure why. Currently walking (and suffering) is how I break in new socks. But, once I make a pair comfortable, I will always choose to wear them. As a result, I am always wearing the same few pair of socks that are comfortable until they form holes and eventually tear apart... this is not a good system for me.

**Basically, how can I take new socks and artificially stretch out the cotton so as to minimize their insulation of my feet**? Note: the elasticity of the sock can't be destroyed because I want to be able to quickly slip my shoes off before going inside. I can't have the socks slip off along with the shoes.

Answer (score 4):

You could buy thinner socks. A quick search for "thin socks" reveals that many clothing shops carry them.

Comment: I think I know the "thin" socks you are referencing. But, they did not last very long. I walked a tear into them pretty quick and they were not that comfortable. I just really like normal cotton socks that have been stretched-out and broken-in.

Comment: @imaichiko try some different kind of thin sock?

Comment: There are many quality thin shocks.

Answer (score 1):

Drying them stretched might work. Cut a feet shape in cardboard that is bigger than the sock and put the sock on it while it is wet. Drying in this condition should help loosen them.

Disclaimer, I never tried it myself for socks. I'm just improvising a hack from an old hack I was using to have longer jeans, hanging them with bricks as I couldn't find jeans long enough for my thin waist.

Answer (score 0):

Small load in the washer, and use dishwashing machine powder instead of clothes detergent. Dishwashing powder has mild abrasives in it and will wear the fibers for you.

Comment: And then residue from this abrasive powder is left in your washing machine?

Comment: Powder clothing detergents contain abrasive particles too.  The rutile that gives *whiter than white* is abrasive.